# Parse Schema Frozen

Tags: parse-server

I have started using the **parse-server** npm module.

Everything starts up fine, but when I attempt to make REST requests to instantiate new objects in a new class, I get the following response:

```
{"code":107,"error":"schema is frozen, cannot add: AccountTest2"}
```

I've tried googling this issue but I am quite literally seeing no results whatsoever.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by dropping the

```
_SCHEMA
```

collection from MongoDB using [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/).

I'm honestly not 100% sure what the _SCHEMA collection is for (looks like it just holds/caches the standard/typical schema for your objects so when you change the object schema we get this frozen error); if someone could enlighten us in this area would be great :)

Comment: On parse/parse-server when you defined a property on an object for the 1st time, we record that type on the _SCHEMA table for your object's class. This is to ensure you don't store mixed types on the same column so you native clients don't have unexpected behaviours. As for why you schema was frozen, that's odd as we don't have that error on parse-server